# Laravel Maatwebsite only readying excel file without create Import & saving file

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

Currently i want to working with excel file. ( with [Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/) )
the step is

1. post upload the file
2. I don't want to store the file first
3. I want to read the excel file , without first creating the Import Class

anyone have the solutions ?

thank you

Comment: what do you mean by `without first creating the Import Class` ?

Comment: I mean without doing something like this php artisan make:import UsersImport --model=User